# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, file, sockets

I am new to Socket programming. I am trying to write a file on server, but my code throws an exception:

> ```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Welcome-PC\IndiraSharing\hadoop.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
> ```

Here is my code.

```
   Socket s;

   ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5555);

   String serveradd;
   serveradd=s.getInetAddress().getHostName();
  //  System.out.println("Server accepted client");
    InputStream input = s.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter outReader = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
    String filename = inReader.readLine();
    if ( !filename.equals("") ){      

        outReader.write("READY\n");
        outReader.flush();
    } 

     FileOutputStream wr = new FileOutputStream(new File(serveradd+"\\IndiraSharing/" +     filename));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[s.getReceiveBufferSize()];
    int bytesReceived = 0;
    while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer))>0)
    {
             wr.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
    }
```

Comment: *"ere is my code."*  Where is your question?

Comment: How are you running your program? IDE, command line? What does your file structure look like?

Comment: Its not full code..show client and server side full code

Comment: First print `filename` that you are reading  from  client. And then see the` filename` in your directry is present or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory cannot be found. The message is confusing because it talks of "file" but in Java IO, a directory is a File too.

If you run:

```
File dir = new File(serveradd+"\\IndiraSharing")
System.out.println(dir.exists());
```

It will print:

```
false
```

You could try to create the directory structure:

```
dir.mkdirs();
```

Also, check the absolute path is what you are expecting:

```
System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: It wasn't intended to be a solution. It was intended to help you debug by narrowing in on the problem, so *you* can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

`Welcome-PC\IndiraSharing\hadoop.txt` is a relative path and I'm sure you should specify a absolute path for your socket program. BTW, the directory should exists even if you want to create a new file.